# Post data from Knockout to Controller using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm getting null for the controller parameter. I am posting data as I can see it in Chrome Developer tools. I have a Person model in MVC that matches the Person model below. This is my ViewModel :

```
 function Person(data) {
    this.FirstName = ko.observable(data.FirstName);
    this.LastName = ko.observable(data.LastName);
    this.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);

    this.fullName = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.FirstName() + " " + this.LastName();
    }, this);

}

function PersonViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.people = ko.observableArray([]);



    $.getJSON("/api/person/getpeople", function (allData) {
        var mappedTasks = $.map(allData, function (item) { return new Person(item) });
        self.people(mappedTasks);
    });


    self.save = function(){

        $.ajax("/api/person/updateperson", {
            data: ko.toJSON({ people: self.people }),
            type: "post", contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result) { alert(result) }
        });
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(new PersonViewModel);
```

API controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public bool UpdatePerson(List<Person> person)
    {
        return mgr.UpdatePerson(person);
    }
```

Comment: parameter name mismatch `person` in controller `people` in js .

Comment: you can simply try this `data: ko.toJSON(self.people ),` no need to mention people . cheers

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the service parameter's names match up with what you're passing.

```
self.save = function(){

        $.ajax("/api/person/updateperson", {
            data: ko.toJSON({ person: self.people }),
            type: "post", contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result) { alert(result) }
        });
    }
```

Comment: The developer tool in Chrome tells me I'm passing:  {people: [{FirstName: "Paul", LastName: "Allen", Id: 17, fullName: "Paul Allen"},…]}

Comment: Right, but you want to change people: to person: in order to match what the C# method is expecting as a parameter

Comment: ok, I changed the code in ajax method to data: ko.toJSON({ person: self.person }), along with the other names of people to person and it is still null.  I have  <ul data-bind="foreach: person">
    <li>
        <input data-bind="value:fullName" />  
    </li>
</ul>  in the html

Comment: Hmm, does the data you're passing to UpdatePerson() look the same?

What's the C# Person class look like?

Comment: The post value is an array of person with 17 entries. My parameter for UpdatePerson is List<Person>

Comment: I think you have the right idea but maybe some variable names in the Person objects don't line up. Capitalization or types can cause things to choke